problem with outputting decoded audio with ffmpeg c++
i am decoding a .mp4 file and want to play decoded raw audio with waveform-audio. it had some problems even tried double buffering but didnt work. it was glitchy and noisy.
i tried gathering all the audio in one buffer but issue wasnt gone.
    SwrContext* swrCtx = nullptr;
    swr_alloc_set_opts2(&swrCtx, &paCodecCtx->ch_layout, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, paCodecCtx->sample_rate, &paCodecCtx->ch_layout, paCodecCtx->sample_fmt, paCodecCtx->sample_rate, 0, nullptr);
    swr_init(swrCtx);

    


      // Initialize the wave format based on decoded audio properties
      waveFormat.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_IEEE_FLOAT;
      waveFormat.nChannels = paCodecCtx->ch_layout.nb_channels;
      waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec = paCodecCtx->sample_rate;
      waveFormat.wBitsPerSample = av_get_bytes_per_sample(paCodecCtx->sample_fmt) * 8;//paCodecCtx->sample_fmt; // Assuming AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16
      waveFormat.nBlockAlign = (waveFormat.nChannels * waveFormat.wBitsPerSample) / 8;
      waveFormat.nAvgBytesPerSec = waveFormat.nSamplesPerSec * waveFormat.nBlockAlign;
      waveFormat.cbSize = 0;

      //after receiving the frame
                    newfr->sample_rate = audioframe->sample_rate;
                    newfr->ch_layout = audioframe->ch_layout;
                    //newfr->ch_layout.nb_channels = audioframe->ch_layout.nb_channels;
                    newfr->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;


                    swr_convert_frame(swrCtx, newfr, audioframe);

      //buffering 
      buffer = (uint8_t*)realloc(buffer,abc+newfr->linesize[0]);
                         memcpy(buffer + abc, newfr->data[0],newfr->linesize[0]);
                         abc +=newfr->linesize[0];


You are assuming the problem is in this piece of decoding logic when it is actually in the enclosing control flow of your program. Please supply a [mre]
